# Access the next item of a tableView populated by a plist

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, plist

I have a tableView populated by a plist.

Each item in the plist has its own id.

The plist is structured like this:

```
Root    
>Item 0
   Title  (Title of the first section in the tableView)
   Rows (Array -> Rows of the first section)
     >Item 0
        id 
        name
        description
        image
     >Item 1
        id 
        name
        description
        image
      //etc
```

Due that an image talks better than 1000 words, here it is:

[image]

Now, I would like to access to the next item of the plist from the detailView, but I don't know how to do or what the mechanism should be like.
I googled a lot to accomplish this but I didn't find anything that could actually help me, that's why I'm asking here.

I already have the plist opened in the detailView (opened from the tableView accessing the id), and I would like to create a button or something to go to the next item.

In example, if the detailView is the id of Item 0, I need to access the next id, which is Item 1 id.

Has anyone done this before?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Could you show some code you use to access plist and display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's so easy, load your plist in DetailView and do the rest.

Comment: The project looks great! Thanks a lot! I'll try that and get back to you

Answer (score 1):

Start by importing the plist (this applies if it is stored in the bundle):

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *file  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Name" ofType:@"plist"];
if (!file) {
        // Handle error if file not found
}
```

Then open the file as a dictionary (I am assuming you don´t need the initial array):

```
// Open the file
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:file];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [array objectAtIndex:0]; // Skipped checking if array is empty
if (!dictionary) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to process plist file");  // Handle error
}
```

Then you can query the dictionary for the object needed, i.e. an array with key @"MyKey" in this case:

```
NSArray *rowArray= [dictionary objectForKey:@"MyKey"];
```

Then you can retrieve next object from the array.